# Get Jira details using python

Tags: python-2.7, api, jira, jira-rest-api, ujson

I have installed ujson and jira package in my server.

I want to fetch details from jira using python in beginning

Code:

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA('https://jira.corp.xyz.com') (comment)
jac = JIRA(server='https://jira.corp.xyz.com', basic_auth=('user_name', 'password'))
issue = jac.issue('DWO-19743')

print(issue)
print(issue.fields.description)
```

But getting error as

```
WARNING:root:HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira.corp.xyz.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)) while doing GET https://jira.corp.xyz.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo [{u'headers': {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', u'Accept': u'application/json,*.*;q=0.9', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', u'X-Atlassian-Token': u'no-check', u'Cache-Control': u'no-cache', u'Content-Type': u'application/json'}, 'params': None}]
WARNING:root:Got ConnectionError [HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira.corp.xyz.com', port=443): Max  Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),))] errno:None on GET https://jira.corp.xyz.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo
{'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}\{'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}
WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET https://jira.corp.xyz.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [2/3] in 35.0706056104s. Err: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira.corp.xyz.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),))
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Is `jira.corp.xyz.com` really the host you are trying to connect to, or maybe copied from example code? No need to say the real host and definitely don't provide username/password here, just something to potentially look at

Comment: No mitoRibo, I have not copied from anywhere and I have changed the host accordingly and didn't share username and password too.